# Modifying part of the url from a <a> tag in Jinja2

Tags: python, html, regex, jinja2

I am using Jinja2, and I have an url:

```
http://mywebsite/blog/en/
```

Just below the header I have three buttons, which are intended to send to the current url, but replacing the last part with the current language. This buttons are rendered by a macro:

```
{% macro Languages(name='', value='', abbreviation='') %}
<button class="Languages">
    <a href="{{name}}">{{name}}</a>
</button>
{{ caller() }}
{% endmacro %}
```

So at the end I have something like:

```
<button class="Languages">
    <a href="en">English</a>
</button>
<button class="Languages">
    <a href="de">Deutsch</a>
</button>
<button class="Languages">
    <a href="es">Español</a>
</button>
```

My question is about how to do this. Is it possible to use some kind of regex to say something like «go to the current url but replacing the text between the last `/` and `/` for an «en» or an «es» or a «de»? I imagine that it should look like `\/\w\w\/`, but I can't imagine how set this in the href=''.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need a fully-qualified URL in your `<a>`? If not, then this should do the trick.

```
<a href="../{{abbreviation}}">{{name}}</a>
```

Here it is in a runnable example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from flask import Flask, request, render_template_string
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/blog/<lang>/')
def blog(lang):
    return render_template_string('''
        {% macro Languages(name='', value='', abbreviation='') %}
        <button class="Languages">
            <a href="../{{abbreviation}}/">{{name}}</a>
        </button>
        {% endmacro %}
        <html><body><form method="post">
            {{Languages('English', '1', 'en')}}
            {{Languages('Spanish', '1', 'es')}}
            {{Languages('French', '1', 'fr')}}
            </form>

            <br>{{lang}} {{ {"en": "hello", "fr": "bon jour", "es": "hola"}[lang] }}
        </body></html>''', lang=lang)

if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, port=8080)
```

Comment: Well, if I could use a proper url that would be great, of course…

Comment: Hm, thanks! I will need to study this a bit, but sounds promising…